# Why is scrolling with ".bind(mousewheel)" so unnatural?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel, behavior

I used ".bind(mousewheel)" to change the rotation of an element but it doesn't feel like the normal scrolling behavior.

There is no easing-out on the scroll, it stops very abruptly and the scroll has always the same speed.

I would like to have the normal scroll, so it is like e.g. the date picker on the iPhone.

I also tried ".bind(scroll)" but it doesn't change anything.

How can I change that?

```js
var counter = 0;
$(document).bind("mousewheel",function(event){
    if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0){
        counter -= 1;
        console.log(counter);
        $(".outer_box").css({"transform":"perspective(1000px) rotateX("+counter+"deg)"})
    }else{
        counter += 1;
        console.log(counter);
        $(".outer_box").css({"transform":"perspective(1000px) rotateX("+counter+"deg)"})
    }
})
```

```css
*,*:after,*:before{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.body-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.main_box{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.outer_box{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(.1deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all .1s cubic-bezier(0.275, 1.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.in_box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.in_box p{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4.5vw;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
}


.in_box:nth-child(1){ transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(2){ transform: rotateX(16.36363636deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(3){ transform: rotateX(32.72727273deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(4){ transform: rotateX(49.09090909deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(5){ transform: rotateX(65.45454545deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(6){ transform: rotateX(81.81818182deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(7){ transform: rotateX(98.18181818deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(8){ transform: rotateX(114.5454545deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(9){ transform: rotateX(130.9090909deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(10){ transform: rotateX(147.2727273deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(11){ transform: rotateX(163.6363636deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(12){ transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(13){ transform: rotateX(196.3636364deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(14){ transform: rotateX(212.7272727deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(15){ transform: rotateX(229.0909091deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(16){ transform: rotateX(245.4545455deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(17){ transform: rotateX(261.8181818deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(18){ transform: rotateX(278.1818182deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(19){ transform: rotateX(294.5454545deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(20){ transform: rotateX(310.9090909deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(21){ transform: rotateX(327.2727273deg) translateZ(27vw); }
.in_box:nth-child(22){ transform: rotateX(343.6363636deg) translateZ(27vw); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="body">


<div class="main_box">
    <div class="outer_box">

        <div class="in_box">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>7</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>8</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>9</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>11</p>
        </div>

        <div class="in_box">
            <p>12</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>13</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>15</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>16</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>17</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>18</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>19</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>20</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>21</p>
        </div>
        <div class="in_box">
            <p>22</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all `mousewheel` is deprecated, and you should use `wheel` instead. Besides that, you should check what the meaning of  `wheelDelta` is, it is not just zero, positive, or negative, but also has a magnitude.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Do you have a similar method in mind how I can achieve that? :)